# How to use the log parser in Windows PowerShell by using for each loops to query the logs from multiple exchange servers?

Tags: exchange-server, powershell-3.0

I would like to use the below mentioned command in windows powershell by using the for each loops. Please let me know if you have any ideas on this query.

As I have little bit idea to input multiple values for the `FROM` parameter as because I need to search logs from the different servers from the given location.

I would like to feed the values for `FROM` filed like below but I don't have an complete idea to create the entire PowerShell script structure.

```
\\server1\d$\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Mapi\*.*
\\server2\d$\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Mapi\*.*
```

Command I created for individual server:

```
LogParser.exe "
    SELECT DateTime,AuthenticatedUser,UserAgent 
    FROM 'd:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Mapi\*.*' 
    WHERE AuthenticatedUser LIKE '%user1%' 
        AND UserAgent LIKE '%Microsoft Office%'" -i:CSV -o:csv > "C:\Log parser\server1\1.csv"
```

Comment: Do you want to run LogParser locally on each remote server?

Comment: Hello Ansgar Wiechers , Thanks for looking in to this query .yes i have installed the log parser on my local machine .By using that i would like to extract the report remotely from multiple servers. I have shared a command for a single server and it is running fine in windows powershell .How i can run the command remotely at a time for multiple servers from my local machine through a powershell ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access to the administrative shares on the remote servers you could do something like this:

```
$servers = 'server1', 'server2', ...
$servers | ForEach-Object {
    LogParser.exe -i:csv -o:csv -q "SELECT DateTime,AuthenticatedUser,UserAgent
        FROM '\\${_}\D$\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Mapi\*.*'
        WHERE AuthenticatedUser LIKE '%user1%' 
            AND UserAgent LIKE '%Microsoft Office%'" |
        Out-File "C:\Log parser\${_}.csv"
}
```